# Svelte transition:fly|local blocks siblings

Tags: svelte

I have a few vertically-aligned buttons I'd like to transition in/out, without blocking the page from navigating away, so they need to use the `local` directive. However, that directive breaks the transition that otherwise works when I don't apply it. Here's the relevant except from my code:

```
<div class="absolute top-0 right-0 mt-12 flex flex-col gap-2">
  {#if $canPublish}
  <div transition:fly|local={{y: 20}}>
    <Anchor type="button-circle" on:click={openAdvanced}>
      <i class="fa fa-sliders" />
    </Anchor>
  </div>
  <div transition:fly|local={{y: 20}}>
    <Anchor type="button-circle" href={`/messages/${npub}`}>
      <i class="fa fa-envelope" />
    </Anchor>
  </div>
  {/if}
  {#if following}
  <div transition:fly|local={{y: 20}}>
    <Anchor type="button-circle" on:click={unfollow}>
      <i class="fa fa-user-minus" />
    </Anchor>
  </div>
  {:else if user.getPubkey() !== pubkey}
  <div transition:fly|local={{y: 20}}>
    <Anchor type="button-circle" on:click={follow}>
      <i class="fa fa-user-plus" />
    </Anchor>
  </div>
  {/if}
  <div transition:fly|local={{y: 20}}>
    <Anchor type="button-circle" on:click={share}>
      <i class="fa fa-share-nodes" />
    </Anchor>
  </div>
</div>
```

And [here](https://dufflepud.us-southeast-1.linodeobjects.com/transition.webp) is a video of what happens with the animation.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Why would not using `local` "block the page from navigating away"?

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a Repl? https://svelte.dev/repl/hello-world?version=3.55.1

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, it looks like nested conditionals block animations. You can see a reproduction of the issue [here](https://svelte.dev/repl/bc560a2ed0584386aa06fe63a5c47d3e?version=3.55.1).

I fixed it by combining the conditionals as in [this example](https://svelte.dev/repl/f9700c04047944919dc5d3ed7e6827dd?version=3.55.1). This makes things more awkward for sure, but I think I can code around it.

Here's what not to do:

```
{#if visible}
<div>
  {#if one}
  <div transition:fly|local>
   one
  </div>
  {/if}
  <div transition:fly|local>
    three
  </div>
</div>
{/if}
```

Nesting conditionals will prevent the inner transition from occurring.

Comment: Links to a Repl are great, but better also include the relevant code in the answer. Aren't you after supressing the transition when the whole block is removed? In your second example all elements do transition when `visible` changes? So `|local` could also be omitted. (When transitioning out the bottom element would usually start first so it would be better if the delay was inversed in this case..) In your first example the element `three` transitions because it doesn't have its 'own block'. When wrapping it in a `{#if true}` all elements would directly appear and vanish.